# .htaccess to change the url path

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have tried several examples of solutions that I have found here on StackOverflow but none of them seem to work correctly.

I have a Magento store that I need to redirect an old store code url to the new one. For example:

The old url looked like this.

www.example.com/something_en

In the above example I need to be able to modify any url that contains to the path `something_en` and change it to `something` like in the next example.

www.example.com/something

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure this is your **very first rule** in main .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^something_en(/.*)?$ /something$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked great! That may have been my main mistake as I was originally adding it to the bottom.

Comment: You're welcome, yes position of these rules is very important.