# Rewrite a folder name add slash using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to use `.htaccess` to rewrite a folder name adding a **slash** inside the name?

Lets say I have a url like:

```
example.com/sub-directory/page.php
```

Now I want to rewrite the url to:

```
example.com/sub/directory/page.php
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess to change the url path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554975/htaccess-to-change-the-url-path)

Comment: @try-catch-finally it's not the same...my problem is the dash in the name, I know how to rewrite in .htaccess but I don't know how to do when a slash is in the middle of the name

Comment: You should be able to under stand that example and change so it meets your requirements. Rewrite is nothing else than having a matcher expression on the left hand side and the new target (replacement) on the other side. Here's [Apache's Rewrite Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html) :)

Comment: Thanks @try-catch-finally, in my case this rule doesn't work `RewriteRule ^sub-folder(/.*)?$ /sub/folder$1 [L,NC,R=301]` that's why I'm here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.php$ /$1/$2/$3.php [NC,L]
```

The regular expression above **^([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([^.]+).php$** will match any request that starts with any character (not -) followed by a **-** followed by any character (not -) followed by a **/** followed by any character (not dot) followed by .php literly. if it matches then the request will be rewritten as **/sub/dir/file.php** .